# How do i compare individual items in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm quite new and still learning python. I need to know how to compare items in a list to another list.

```
mc_zip = zip(name, class)
mc_list = list(mc_zip)
class_zip = zip(class_name, class_number)
class_list = list(class_zip)
print(mc_list)
print(class_list)
```

output

```
mc_list = [('AA', 5537), ('AA', 5620), ...., ('AB', 5531)]
class_list = [('AA', 5537), ('AA', 1244), ...., ('AZ', 4545)]
```

`mc_list` is the students that did not attend class while the `class_list` is the list of students at the school. I would like to know how can I compare the names of the `mc_list` to the `class_list` and after that be able to pluck out the data from the `mc_list` that has the same name. So that I can know the classes that particular name took.
The new output should be:

```
mcstudentclass = [('AA', 5537),('AA', 5540), ('AA', 1244),('AB', 5531), ('AB', 6636),.....]
```

If you are wondering where ('AB', 6636) or ('AA', 5540) come from. It came from class_list the .... (....)represents over a few repeating names that have different class numbers and vice versa.
Sorry if it is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Are you saying `class_list` has the list of classes each student signed up for, and `mc_list` has the list of classes they skipped, and you want to know which classes they attended?  BTW, you should never name a variable "class".  That's a Python statement.

Comment: Are you saying you want to create a new list made up of elements that exist in both lists?

Comment: How do you want to compare them exactly? Like, intersection or subtraction, or something more complicated? Please [edit] to clarify. It'd help a lot to add example input and desired output. C.f. [mre].

Comment: Hi, so class_list is basically the names of students and the classes they have. each student can have up to more than one class. mc list is the name of students and the class number of the class they skipped. Right now I need to compare the name of mc_list and class_list so that I can get the all class number that they need to attend. I also would want it to be in list like the above output.

Comment: Where does `('AB', 6636)` come from? Please provide *complete* example input and output.

Comment: ('AB', 6636) come from class_list the .... (....)represents over a few repeating names that have different class numbers and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the list of classes that people attended from the list of classes they are registered for and the list of classes they missed, here are two options, which start with the same zipped format you provided.

```py
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]
classes = [1, 2, 3]
registered = [("Alice", 1), ("Alice", 2), ("Alice", 3), ("Bob", 2), ("Bob", 3), ("Charlie", 1), ("Charlie", 3)]
missed = [("Alice", 1), ("Charlie", 3)]
# 1. list comprehension
attended = [p for p in registered if p not in missed]
print(attended)
# 2. set difference
attended = set(registered) - set(missed)
print(attended)
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the class list in a dictionary.
The compare the mc_list to it.
It will save a lot of time.

If compare a list against a list it has to traverse the list.
I dictionary look up doesn't require that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).